# How to add AWS elasticache autoscaling with target value more then 70?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, autoscaling, amazon-elasticache

Due to [AWS elasticache autoscaling documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/AutoScaling-Scaling-Adding-Policy-Shards.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped) target metric value must be

> greater than or equal to 35 and less than or equal to 70

[image: AWS elasticache autoscaling docs]

But value 70 is normal for my cluster.

How can I made elasticache cluster autoscaling with target metric value 90?

Comment: My thoughts on tis topc:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of investigation:

I created a CloudWatch alarm on target value 98.
Also, I made an EventBridge event to trigger lambda function on alarm.
In the lambda function, I used Python and AWS CLI command

```
aws elasticache modify-replication-group-shard-configuration \
--replication-group-id <name> \
--node-group-count 3 \
--apply-immediately
```

So I created my own autoscaling :)